# install gem mysql2 in ubuntun15.10?

Tags: rubygems, installation, mysql2

when i type: gem install mysql2

it shows error:

gem install mysql2                                                    100 ↵
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.3/CHANGELOG.md